# If $E_i$ is compact, then $\cup_{i=1}^{n} E_{i}$ is compact? $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_{i}$ is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $E_i$ is compact, then $\cap_{i=1}^{n} E_i$ is compact:

Since $E_i$ is compact then it is closed and bounded

Then there exists $a_i$ and $b_i$ such that for all $x \in E_i$, $a_i \leq x \leq b_i$

Choose $a=max\{a_i\}$ and $b=min\{b_i\}$

Then fall $x\in \cap_{i=1}^{n} E_i$, $a \leq x \leq b$

So $\cap_{i=1}^{n} E_i$ is bounded

Next we show $\cap_{i=1}^{n}E_i$ is closed

Assume $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $\cap_{i=1}^{n} E_i$

Then there exists a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset \cap_{i=1}^{n} E_i$ such that $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_{k} = x_0$

There must exist $E_i$ such that there are infinite $\{x_k\}$ belonging to $E_i$

So $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $E_i$ i.e. $E_i$ is closed

$\Rightarrow x_0 \in E_i$ and $x_0 \in \cap_{i=1}^{n} E_i$

Therefore $\cap_{i=1}^{n} E_i$ is closed and bounded, thus compact.

Does that sound right for that proof?

For If $E_i$ is compact, then $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$ is compact?

I was thinking that since you are taking the intersection of these sets then the values will continue to get smaller and smaller until the limit just becomes a singleton element, but would that types of set be closed and bounded?

Answer (score 2):

Any intersection of compact sets is compact.  Unions of compact sets are not necessarily compact.  Just look at

$$(0,1) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [1/n, 1 - 1/n].$$

Comment: The question doesn’t ask about infinite unions.

Comment: Finite unions are compact.